# Using Chrome extension to open window with multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

On the CRM I am working on I have a requirement that clicking on a certain button will open new Chrome Window that can have multiple tabs. In Firefox this works with the regular `window.open()` but in Chrome the popup window that opens can only have one tab (accessible to js anyhow)

To solve this I need to create a Chrome extension that will only run in *.mydomain.* that that has access to the Chrome Extension API which js on my site will call - EventListener or Message

I envision it will work like this

1. Js on my site triggers event that contains the URL to open in new Window
2. Extension receives URL and opens a new Chrome Window
3. As an added bonus - new window will open up on other screen in a 2 monitor setup
4. js in URL will open up multiple urls in new tabs in same window

I was looking [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and am a little confused how to classify the extension type that I need - Event Page/Content Script/Background Page etc. - and where to put the code - content.js / background.js
I would also appreciate some pointers to the correct API I need to do this

This will NOT be going to the Chrome Webstore and I DO have access to the computers running Chrome to install the extension.